# Build a flat List from a Tree structure in Java

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I have a Tree structure represented by a `List`, which I want to get it flattened.

I wrote the function below:

```
List<Entry> flatTree(List<Entry> toFlat, List<Entry> destination) {
    for (Entry entry : toFlat) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(entry.getEntries())) {
            this.flatTree(entry.getEntries(), destination);
        } else {
            destination.add(entry);
        }
    }
    return destination;
}
```

used in this way:

```
List<Entry> flattenedEntries = this.flatTree(entries, new ArrayList<>());
```

with this kind of input (`entries`):

```
[
    {
        key: "level1.1",
        entries: [] 
    },
    {
        key: "level1.2",
        entries: [
            {
                key: "level2.1",
                entries: [] 
            }
        ]   
    },
    {
        key: "level1.3",
        entries: [
            {
                key: "level2.2",
                entries: [] 
            },
            {
                key: "level2.3",
                entries: [
                    {
                        key: "level3.1",
                        entries: [] 
                    }
                ]   
            }
        ]   
    }
]
```

What I'm going to achieve is to have a list containing only objects with keys: `level1.1, level2.1, level2.2, level3.1` or rather, all the elements that has no sub elements `entries`.

Each object has just 2 properties inside: `key` and `entries`.

It works, but I would like to avoid the side effect on the `List<Entry> destination`. Is there a better way to write it?

Comment: You’ll need to add more context.  What is an `Entry`?  Does it have more info than is shown in your JSON?   Why are you adding the entry that contains no subentry, but you don’t add an entry that contains other entries?  Do you have two types of entries: containers & leafs?  Are you losing the `key` data?

Comment: Hi, I just added more information. Should be enough to understand what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question from the [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229557/build-a-flat-list-from-a-tree-structure-in-java/229627#comment446796_229627) on RoToRa's answer:

> Thanks! I wonder if there is any way to do this by using, for example, just the Java 8 Stream API or something similar, to have it in just one line of code.

### Using the Java Stream API

Assuming the following `Entry` class:

```
public class Entry {
   final String key;
   final List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

   Entry(String _key, Entry ...children) {
      key = _key;
      entries.addAll(Arrays.asList(children));
   }

   public List<Entry> getEntries() {
      return Collections.unmodifiableList(entries);
   }

   public String toString() {
      return key;
   }
}
```

We can build up the example input with:

```
List<Entry> top = new ArrayList<>();
top.add(new Entry("level1.1"));
top.add(new Entry("level1.2", new Entry("level2.1")));
top.add(new Entry("level1.3", new Entry("level2.2"), new Entry("level2.3", new Entry("level3.1"))));
```

From @RoToRa's answer, we'll borrow these method signatures:

```
public static List<Entry> flatTree(List<Entry> toFlat) {
   return flatTree(toFlat, ArrayList::new);
}

public static List<Entry> flatTree(List<Entry> toFlat, Supplier<List<Entry>> listSupplier) {
```

Now, to flatten with the Stream API, (the **requested "one line of code"**), we'd want to write something like:

```
   return toFlat.stream().flatMap(Entry::leaves)
                         .collect(Collectors.toCollection(listSupplier));
}
```

So, we'll need to define `Entry::leaves` to extract only the leaves from our tree:

```
public static Stream<Entry> leaves(Entry entry) {
   if (entry.getEntries().size() > 0)
      return entry.getEntries().stream().flatMap(Entry::leaves);
   else
      return Stream.of(entry);
}
```

And on the sample data:

```
jshell> System.out.println(Entry.flatTree(top));
[level1.1, level2.1, level2.2, level3.1]

jshell>
```

Comment: Nice ideas, but I'm not a big fan of having `.stream().flatMap(Entry::leaves)` twice in there.

Comment: @RoToRa `Entry::leaves` is recursive.  You need to call it at least once somewhere, and then it must call itself to descend into the tree branches.  Ego, it must appear twice.  Hard to do recursion any other way.  I dislike the top-level `toFlat.stream().flatMap(...)`, but the problem description has a list of trees at the top level instead of one root tree node, which causes some of the repetition of code.

Comment: You've got a good point there. There was something bothering me, and you are right, it's because the input is a list of (root) nodes, instead of a single root. That's a continuation of confusion due to the misnaming of the original method `flatTree`: Not only is the "flat" part wrong, because it's not a flattening but retrieving of leaves, but the "tree" part is also wrong, because is not a about a single tree, but multiple trees.

Answer (score 2):

<del>First off, I'm assuming the call of the method `flatEntriesMap` is wrong and it should be a recursive call to `flatTree`.</del> (EDIT: Source code has been corrected.)

Then you should reconsider the name, especially considering the confusion before your edit: You are not flatting the tree, but retrieving its leaves.

To get rid of the side effect, you simply make the original method `private` and wrap a new method around it that creates the destination list:

```
public List<Entry> flatTree(List<Entry> toFlat) {
    return this.flatTree(toFlat, new ArrayList<>());
}
```

In case you need to be able to determine the type of list returned from the outside, then instead of passing a new instance pass a supplier that creates the instance:

```
public List<Entry> flatTree(List<Entry> toFlat, Supplier<List<Entry>> listSupplier) {
    return this.flatTree(toFlat, listSupplier.get());
}
```

which can then be called either with

```
flatTree(entries, () -> new ArrayList<>());
```

or

```
flatTree(entries, ArrayList::new);
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if there is any way to do this by using, for example, just the Java 8 Stream API or something similar, to have it in just one line of code.

Comment: @grimi I was thinking about suggesting streams, but I couldn't figure out a nice way to do it, that is actually better than without. I'll do more thinking about it.